# Create String Array from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am trying to make a more dynamic solution of what I currently have. I have a database with a number of cases where each case consists of 2 assignments. In my view I want to show each case according to each assignment:

---

```
Case   |  Assignment   |  SelecteBool
Case1  |  Electricity  |  true
Case2  |  Electricity  |  false
Case1  |  Cement       |  true
Case2  |  Cement       |  false
```

---

I have created a code that makes this view possible but only with a manual created String Array where I define each assignment:

```
string[] assignments = new string[2];
assignments[0] = "Electricity";
assignments[1] = "Cement";
```

My problem is that if a case in the future should contain 3 (or more) assignments I have to manually go in and add that to the list. Is it possible to create a dynamic solution that will read the selected case assignments and put them into a String Array?

For example if Case1 has added one more assingment "Others" and is selected (selectBool == true), then it should read in an array consisting of:

```
assignments[0] = "Electricity";
assignments[1] = "Cement";
assignments[2] = "Others";
```

I am working on MVC5 which consists of a lot of Razor and Linq and I would like to avoid as much javascript as possible.

All help is very much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

As requested here is my View. I am currently not using anything in my controller to create the view with the manual created String Array.

**View:**

```
@{
string[] assignments = new string[2];
assignments[0] = "Electricity";
assignments[1] = "Cement";
}

    <div>

        @foreach (string i in assignments)
        {
            foreach (var chosen in Model)
            {
                if (chosen.SelectedBool == true && chosen.Assignment.Contains(i))
                {
                <div class="table" style=" display: table; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; ">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => chosen.Name)</b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <p><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => chosen.Assignment)</b></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => chosen.SelectedBool)</p>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                }        
            }     
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: please show your view/model/controller

Comment: Added to the question. :) I am only using razor in the view to create my current solution. So I only post my View because I dont use anything in the controller to create my current solution. Please let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignments should be populated in controller ! The easiest way is to set some ViewBag property and then change your view so that loop go through this ViewBag property.
Respectively your controller will have like

```html
ViewBag.Assignments = RetreiveAssignments();
```

and your assignments will be dynamic